# Flex scan only the first one

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

So i have this piece of code ,im trying to make it repeatedly scaning a file ,
line after line but it scan only for the first one.

Any clue why this happens ? Thanks.

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "token.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void yyerror(char *s);

%}

%%
([0,1,8,9]{1})([0-9]{2})([0,1,2]{1})([0-9]{2})  { printf("CSE  Line : %d \n",yylineno); return NUMBER;}
([5-9]|10)["."][0-9]{1,2}   { printf("MO : \n"); return MO;}
\t  { printf("Tab \n"); return TAB;}
\n  { printf("Line cutter \n"); return ALGR;}
%%

void yyerror (char *s) {

   fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);

 }

int main(){

    FILE *myFile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(!myFile){
        printf("Error Opening \n") ; 
        return -1;
    }
    yyin = myFile; 
    yylex();

}
```

Comment: Flex defines a scanner function that scans **one** token and returns information about it.  If you want to scan multiple tokens then it is your responsibility, one way or another, to provide for calling the scanner function multiple times.  By calling it inside a loop, for example.

Comment: I mean something like have 2-3 numbers in my file and check them all ,not actually call the file again and again. 1 time but for all my numbers inside that file.txt .Is that posssible without bison ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about calling *the file* again and again.  I suggested calling the scanner *function* again and again, for which I assumed you would set up the input file only once.

Comment: However, the scanner function will return prior to end-of-file only if it executes a `return` statement in the action for a token it has matched.  Whether there are `return` statements in your actions is under your control.

Comment: Any idea how i do that? Call the scanner to scan the entire file.txt ??

Comment: Nevermind found it, thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yyin = myFile; 
while(yylex());
fclose(yyin);
```

Found the solution.Needed a while outside of lex();

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `yylex`, then why have those return statements in the first place?

Comment: You mean this for FILES , or the tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the return statements from the rules, `yylex` won't return until it has read the entire file

```
%%
([0,1,8,9]{1})([0-9]{2})([0,1,2]{1})([0-9]{2})  { printf("CSE  Line : %d \n",yylineno);}
([5-9]|10)["."][0-9]{1,2}   { printf("MO : \n");}
\t  { printf("Tab \n");}
\n  { printf("Line cutter \n");}
%%
```